# How to write inline c# code in master page of asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline-code

I want to write inline c# code in aspx page. From googling I get that I have to add `Page Language = "C#"`. But in master page the Language is already defined. Is there any other way to do that?

I want to add `<% DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(); %>` at the footer.

One way to do that is to use `Literal` and update it on page load. I'm looking for any other way.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, "Language is already defined"?

Comment: What's unclear about the message? Why is there a spurious `Page` word? This does not make any sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `=` sign at the start.

```
   <%= DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>
```

Which is the same as writing

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```

in the code behind.

Yes this works on webforms.

Answer (score -1):

i just cant see the problem!
any where inside the master page you can just embed C# with no pro

```
    <% DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
```

Comment: I'm using .aspx as web-page not MVC.